# Very Slow Mining on CPU with 8 Core Xeon E5-2660

Tags: cpu-mining, miner-configuration

I have a 8 Core Xeon E5-2660 machine with 16GB Ram (without GPU). I have used ByteCoin and MinerGate both of which gave me just 90-100 Hashes/sec.
I see people talking about 2-4 MH/s whereas I am getting only a fraction of that. Could anybody please tell me where I am going wrong, what should I do to get such hash rates.

The hardware and electricity both are free for me. Basically I have no expenses. So please give the instructions so that I can make the most of it. Which currency, miner, drivers, etc to use.

Comment: related: [In the ASIC-age, is it even worth starting casual mining at home?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406)

Answer (score 0):

You have no hardware that is suitable for mining, so your mining rate is going to be atrocious. You'll never make enough to compensate for the extra wear and tear on your expensive, general purpose hardware.